# Strange edit suggestions. Where did that crap come from?

Tags: discussion

I found this very strange edit [suggestion](https://unix.stackexchange.com/suggested-edits/2278) for one of my answers. To me it looks like some bot tried to put some infection links there.

Any ideas what that was/is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like bot spam. That's all.

Comment: Yes - but how can a bot suggest an edit?

Comment: That sounds like a question for Stack Overflow! In seriousness, it's either a low-paid human doing sad, sad grunt-work, or else a moderately clever script.

Comment: I did not know that is was so easy to edit as anonymous user. Is there not some captchure-barrier or something like that?